# How to fix elements appearing behind video

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how to fix and why the `<div>` and `<p>` under the video with an image over goes under the video and not below the video?

```css
#contain {
  position: relative;
}

video {
  object-fit: fill;
}

video {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
}

#img {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="contain">
  <div id="img">
    <a style="color:white; font-family:verdana;" title="Home">
      <img src="purefilmsw.png" alt="Pure Films" width="912.5" height="58.5">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="vid">
    <video id="background-video" autoplay loop muted>
            <source src="vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
  </div>
</div>
<p>when code is run this goes under video</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think since your #video is an absolute position, it is being put above all the way to the top, try putting the `z-index` of it 2 and the `z-index` of the p tag (target by an id) to something higher than 2

Comment: is there away to have them under like not behind but below on the page?

Comment: You can’t use absolute position. You can set the height and width to 100vh and 100vw and everything else will come under it as long as its not absolute position.